# Clean way to handle moment(undefined) in REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

In REACT application I have a field of type="datetime-local" which uses date from java API which is of type java.util.Date.

For formatting I used:

```
value={moment(
{ ...this.state.startDate[0] }["startTime"]
).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm")}
```

when startDate is undefined i get current time in the field. I need no content when the data is undefined (rather than displaying current timestamp)

I did bit of research and found that moment(undefined) is same as moment() unlike moment(null).

I tried with .isValid() , this also yields incorrect boolean value for undefined .

I am able to handle this by doing check with undefined and using conditional ternany operator.

`({typeof { { ...this.state.startDate[0] }["startTime"] === "undefined" ? [DO NOT USE MOMENT] : [USE MOMENT CODE]})`

IS THERE ANY OTHER CLEAN WAY TO ACHIEVE THIS ?

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` is a falsey value, so a cleaner solution may just be to test the truthy-ness of the start time.

```
{ ...this.state.startDate[0] }["startTime"] ? [DO NOT USE MOMENT] : [USE MOMENT CODE]
```

```js
const badDate = undefined;

const d = badDate && moment(badDate);

console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isValid() method of a moment variable instance like in the following snippet:

```
moment("not a real date").isValid();
```

More info can be found here:

https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: console.log(moment(undefined).isValid());     -------------TRUE 

whereas 

console.log(moment("undefined").isValid());   ------------FALSE